# Unable to run appium tests on iOS real device using windows 10 machine

Tags: java, ios, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to run my appium tests on iPhone 5S which has plugged into Windows 10 computer. But It is not working. Can someone help me how to run the appium tests on iOS real device by using a Windows PC? Below are the desired capabilities I have used.

```
    public class WebTest {
      AppiumDriver driver;
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

     @BeforeClass()
     public void init() throws MalformedURLException {
       capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
       capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 5s");
       capabilities.setCapability("browser", "safari");
        driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
            capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

 @Test
  public void googleTest() {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is impossible to automate iOS device on Windows because XCode is unavailable for Windows. 
You could try to run Virtual Machine with MacOS and run automated tests from there. 
There's [this site](https://experitest.com/appium-studio) which allows you to automate remote device from Windows machine (paid, probably).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. To run iOS Automation the below two is required.

1. Mac OSX
2. XCode w/ Command Line Tools

Answer (score 0):

Use a cloud based service to run your automation scripts on real iOS devices. Example for such services: BrowserStack, SauceLabs etc.

However if you only wish to run it only on the phone you connected, you will need a mac with Xcode and necessary configuration(Appium, debug-proxy for iOS etc)

Comment: Actually can use SauceLabs. But the test is only run in a simulator. And only we'll have a video for the execution. So the test execution report won't contain the errors and screenshots in that way. BTW can use Protractor to run test in actual devices. But I am not sure that will solve the reporting issue.

Comment: I have used browserstack in the past and they offer real ios devices for testing. For reporting, the takesscreenshot method works out of the box on any cloud service provider. You may see issues with protractor tests on real iOS devices since there are open issues related to angular sync and executeAsync on real iOS devices

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the reply @Bounty